# How to get group-wise diagonal values with imputing a dummy row if required?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

I am attaching the sample INPUT file and the Required OUTPUT. I need group-wise diagonal values and to be placed in another new column as `New_Col`. Sometimes a row may be missing as in the case of Group 4. We will have introduce (Impute a row with Zeros) a row with zero values so that the diagonal values can be easily picked. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts fo this question. For the diagonal part you can create a variable that resets itself if reaches the same size as the var columns you have. Then you need to isolate the index over row num and us it to check the if the correspondig row is going to take a value from the data or is going to be zero

```
import numpy as np

ap=np.random.rand(5,3)
index=[0,1,2,0,2]
container=[]
i=0
k=0
while k<len(ap):
  try:
    if index[k]!=i:
      container.append(0)
    else:
      container.append(ap[k,i])
      k=k+1
    i=i+1
    if i==ap[0].size:
      i=0
  except IndexError:
    break
```

Hope it helps